# Can the Airbus A380 safely fly with two engines out on the same wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, engine-failure, aircraft-certification, airbus-a380

I know twin-engine jets can safely take off and fly with one engine out (i.e. all thrust only on one side).  Of course quad-engine jets are also able to fly safely in case one engine is out.

But is the A380 designed to also fly safely in case **two** engines *on the same wing* are out?

Would the rudder be able to compensate the thrust imbalance?

I'm referring to an engine-out situation in flight, not during take off.  I would assume that the problems aggravate during take off since the rudder has less airflow to counter the imbalance.

Note: Two engines out on the same wing is not a very likely scenario, but it's not impossible.  For example, on [Qantas 32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas_Flight_32), damage from the number 2 engine explosion impacted fuel and control lines of engine 1.

Comment: Just as an aside, I don't believe that the A380 is certified to takeoff with two engines out, regardless of which wing they're on. So it's slightly more than "aggravated" during takeoff :) good question regarding in-flight, though

Comment: [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_engine) is relevant.

Comment: I imagine the answer to this question would be the same if you replaced "Airbus A380" in the question with any other passenger airliner with four jet engines.

Comment: I don't think any twin jet can safely take off with one engine out.  V<sub>rotate</sub> would not be achieved soon enough and would necessarily require aborting takeoff.  The tough decision would be if an engine failed just after rotation, what is the best course of action:  land immediately (possibly rolling off the runway end), or try to go round.

Comment: @wallyk -- in your failure-at-rotation case, since you're above V1, you continue the takeoff.  The only cases where you wouldn't is if your engine didn't just quit, but turned into a big drag bucket that's keeping you from maintaining flying speed (certain propeller failures on turboprops can do this, and so can reverser deployment on a jet; it's also possible to get this with gross engine damage.)

Comment: If a third engine went, would the final one provide enough thrust to maintain level flight?

Comment: @trengot You'd be in a slow driftdown in that case -- cascading engine failures in multi-engine aircraft are *exceedingly* rare though, the only instance I have heard of was with a Kalitta Air B742 that had multiple marginal engines on it, so when power was applied after the first engine failure, the remaining engines went as well, one by one.  (It's actually more common for all engines to fail at once due to issues like fuel exhaustion, volcanic ash, etal.)

Comment: @wallyk All twin jet passenger airliners are certified to continue a takeoff and climb-out if an engine fails after V1. If an engine fails before V1, they'll abort the takeoff, but they'll continue if it fails after V1. This happens occasionally in practice, such as in bird-strike events. For example, [here's a 757 continuing with an engine failure after V1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KhZwsYtNDE) and [here's an A330 aborting during a failure before V1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PS1YAX70edc).

Comment: I routinely train pilots in the 380 sim to make 2 engine-out approaches; the aeroplane behaves very well....so long as you understand the aerodynamics involved.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject: I've found another example: in 2013, the #2 engine came off the wing of a modified 707 and knocked the inlet cowling off the #1 engine in the process.  This caused the #1 engine, although still running, to not produce enough thrust to counter the drag it caused; with (effectively) two engines out,  the plane was unable to maintain flight, and the captain made a forced landing on what was left of the runway.  Everyone made it out OK, although the plane was destroyed.  [Link here.](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAB1301.pdf)

Comment: @Sean -- yeah, I'm aware of the N707AR mishap -- that was a case where the #1 engine was effectively producing negative thrust, which put the asymmetric thrust outside the certification limits.

Comment: @wallyk twins have enough spare power to take off on 1 engine.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Proving that a multi-engine aircraft is flyable with one or more engines inoperative is part of the certification programme. The Airbus A380 is certified under FAR (Federal Aviation Regulations, USA) part 25 and JAR (Joint Aviation Regulations, Europe) part 25. One of the requirements of FAR/JAR 25 is that the directional control can be maintained when two critical engines (that means under the same wing) fail.

The following is selectively extracted from [FAR part 25](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr25_main_02.tpl) (JAR is similar, there are some differences). Emphasis added by me.

> **Controllability and Maneuverability**
>
> **§25.143   General.**
>
> ....
>
> **b**) It must be possible to make a smooth transition from one flight
>   condition to any other flight condition without exceptional piloting
>   skill, alertness, or strength, and without danger of exceeding the
>   airplane limit-load factor under any probable operating conditions,
>   including—
>
> 1. The sudden failure of the critical engine;
> 2. For **airplanes with three or more engines**, the sudden **failure of
>      the second critical engine** when the airplane is in the en route,
>      approach, or landing configuration and is trimmed with the critical
>      engine inoperative;
>
> ...

$ $

> **§25.147   Directional and lateral control.**
>
> **a**)  Directional control; general. It must be possible, with the wings
>   level, to yaw into the operative engine and to safely make a
>   reasonably sudden change in heading of up to 15 degrees in the
>   direction of the critical inoperative engine. This must be shown at
>   1.3 V<sub>SR1</sub> for heading changes up to 15 degrees (except that the heading change at which the rudder pedal force is 150 pounds need not be
>   exceeded), and with—
>
> 1. The critical engine inoperative and its propeller in the minimum
>      drag position;
> 2. The power required for level flight at 1.3 V<sub>SR1</sub>, but not more than
>      maximum continuous power;
> 3. The most unfavorable center of gravity;
> 4. Landing gear retracted;
> 5. Flaps in the approach position; and
> 6. Maximum landing weight.
>
> **b**) Directional control; airplanes with **four or more engines**.
>   Airplanes with four or more engines must meet the requirements of
>   paragraph (a) of this section except that—
>
> 1. The **two critical engines must be inoperative** with their propellers
>      (if applicable) in the minimum drag position;
> 2. [Reserved]
> 3. The flaps must be in the most favorable climb position.
>
> **c**) ...
>
> ...
>
> **d**) ...
>
> **e**) Lateral control; **airplanes with four or more engines**. Airplanes
>   with four or more engines must be able to make 20° banked turns, with
>   and against the inoperative engine**s**, from steady flight at a speed
>   equal to 1.3 VSR1, with maximum continuous power, and with the
>   airplane in the configuration prescribed by paragraph (b) of this
>   section.
>
> **f**) ...

$ $

> **§25.149   Minimum control speed.**
>
> ...
>
> **g**) For airplanes with three or more engines, V<sub>MCL-2</sub>, the minimum control speed during approach and landing with one critical engine
>   inoperative, is the calibrated airspeed at which, when a second
>   critical engine is suddenly made inoperative, it is possible to
>   maintain control of the airplane with both engines still inoperative,
>   and maintain straight flight with an angle of bank of not more than 5
>   degrees. V<sub>MCL-2</sub> must be established with—
>
> 1. ...
>
>    ...

$ $

> **§25.161   Trim.**
>
> ...
>
> **e**) Airplanes with four or more engines. Each airplane with four or
>   more engines must also maintain trim in rectilinear flight with the
>   most unfavorable center of gravity and at the climb speed,
>   configuration, and power required by §25.123(a) for the purpose of
>   establishing the en route flight paths with two engines inoperative.

Comment: A long answer, but very informative.  Could you describe briefly (or link to such description) what JAR and FAR are?

Comment: JAR and FAR are the aviation regulations of Europe and the USA. Some parts address design of aircraft, other parts address operations, licensing etc. The JARs are gradually being replaced by EASA (European Aviation Safety Agency) specifications.

Comment: So they only require that the aircraft remain controllable if the crew has time to compensate for the first engine failure before the second one fails - meaning that two engines on the same side going down simultaneously could potentially result in a loss of control?

Answer (score 5):

> Would the rudder be able to compensate the thrust imbalance?

It depends.

The best way to translate those regulations into practical examples is to look at the certification of the A330 and A340-300, which have approximately the same amount of total thrust, the difference being the engine configuration.

Takeoff performance requirements are predicated on 1-engine out for both configurations. Hence you'll notice that the minimum climb gradient requirement means that the 4-engine loses less thrust, hence is capable of a higher takeoff weight; around   30-40T more.

Two engine out comes into play during the landing config, where VMCL2, two engine out minimum control speed in the landing config, is much higher than VMCL1; two engine out 340 has approximately the same amount of thrust as a one engine out 330, but the thrust line produces a greater moment on the 340. Incidentally these speeds don't change with weight and depend on handling qualities and directional control at the most unfavorable CG position, which is the AFT limit. VMCL2 is around 160 knots, which is well above normal landing speed, so at some point during the approach when landing is assured, the pilot will elect to reduce below the VMCL2 to normal landing speed. It will not be possible to select full thrust without losing directional control in this regime of flight, however the benefits of landing at lower speed offset this.

Back to the takeoff case with two engines inoperative, although VMCL is not specifically defined for takeoff config and regulations don't specifically cover this scenario, at higher takeoff weights minimum control speed becomes less of an issue compared to VS1G and overall climb performance. While at lighter weights, it maybe possible to reduce thrust to maintain control if performance permits.